# how laravel blade to merge request segment into url router in layout?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-routing

*I'm develop in Laravel, with Router, Request, Blade (I think that's all related)*

### I need product filter menu at layout.blade.php

It does filter and menu like below

```
locations > east, west, south, north
category > shop, f&b, services
is_new > new, all
```

So then I make the the router as below

```
Route::get('/at/{location_id?}/{location?}/{category_id?}/{category?}/{is_new?}',array('as'=>'deals','uses'=>'HomeController@index'));
```

### Current solution on my menu

I need a menu in layout.blade.php and generate url based on the user selected location, category, is_new. and this layout used for other actions as well.

I don't know how to do these logic on layout. and the solution I got at the end kinda trick.

```
      <ul id='nav-category' class="dropdown-menu extended">
        @if (Request::segment(1)=='deals')
          @foreach (Deal::$categories as $category)
            <li><a href='{{route("deals",array("location_id"=>Request::segment(3),"location"=>Request::segment(4),"category_id"=>$category["id"],"category"=>Str::slug($category["title"])))}}'>{{$category['title']}}</a></li>
          @endforeach
        @else
          @foreach (Deal::$categories as $category)
            <li><a href='{{route("deals",array("location_id"=>"all","category_id"=>$category["id"],"category"=>Str::slug($category["title"])))}}'>{{$category['title']}}</a></li>
          @endforeach
        @endif
      </ul>
```

### Problem

- using Request::segment to get the state don't seem very right
- may have more conditions come in and mess up the blade

This is should be a common problem, but somehow I can't find a good practice. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

For the parameters within the url you can use;

```
Route::current()->parameter('location_id|location|category_id');
```

Meaning your never limited to changing the url pattern within your routes, only limited to what you call the parameter you are passing.

With Request::segment(1)=='deals', there is no other way apart from;

```
@if(Request::is('deals/*'))
```

As this will check the pattern of the url to be anything starting with 'deals/'.